Problem with SSH Key access to Linode Ubuntu 22.04 cloud server from windows Powershell
I have been trying to ssh into my linode server using an rsa ssh key and I have been struggling for several days now. I have copied the public key file into my authorized_keys file in my server, I have chmod'ed the .ssh directory to 700, and the keys to 600. I have tried using putty and passing it the diret putty .ppk rsa key but still no dice. When I try I keep having the following log:
    PS C:\Users\kingr> ssh -vvv kingr@xxx.xxx.xx.xx
    OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/config error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
    debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xxx.xxx.xx.xx is address
    debug2: ssh_connect_direct
    debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xx.xx [xxx.xxx.xx.xx] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
    debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: Authenticating to xxx.xxx.xx.xx as 'kingr'
    debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xxx.xxx.xx.xx
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
    debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-        v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
    debug3: send packet: type 20
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug3: receive packet: type 20
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
    debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
    debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
    debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: languages ctos:
    debug2: languages stoc:
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0
    debug2: reserved 0
    debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
    debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-s,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
    debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
    debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: languages ctos:
    debug2: languages stoc:
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0
    debug2: reserved 0
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug3: send packet: type 30
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug3: receive packet: type 31
    debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ec2/j/PCgSgG1lwgiUZk2KDPrMHob7MRMAIxHaH/VhY
    debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xxx.xxx.xx.xx
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/kingr/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
    debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug3: send packet: type 21
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug3: receive packet: type 21
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
    debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
    debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ys2qbWzhQ16IqozeUL4R7D3uwg0+j75tN3qChnBEEuY
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
    debug3: send packet: type 5
    debug3: receive packet: type 7
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: ping@openssh.com (unrecognised)
    debug3: receive packet: type 6
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
    debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
    debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ys2qbWzhQ16IqozeUL4R7D3uwg0+j75tN3qChnBEEuY
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\kingr/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug3: authmethod_lookup password
    debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
    debug1: Next authentication method: password
    debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
    debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory

Can anyone help me with this??? I've tried ALL the documentation and no fix :(

It is, apologies.

Perhaps you could include how you generated the keypair - you mention PuTTY / .ppk, so should we assume you used puttygen and then converted the .ppk file to OpenSSH format? As well, how exactly did you copy the public key to the server?

Looks like a windows issue regarding the .ssh directory. Mine recently got messed up because of the security settings of users that have access.

AFAIK the debug3 exchange send packet: type 50 followed by receive packet: type 51 pretty much means that the key was sent, but rejected (SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE) - see for example SSH debug packet types

Key was at first created using putty gen then I scrapped it. I overwrote it with a new key using ssh-keygen in openssh in Powershell. I found the .pub file and then copied all of the text (literally ctrl-c) and pasted it into the authorized_keys file after sshing and password authing into my server using nano

Any clue as to why the key might be getting rejected?

Is it possible that the text editor in which you opened the .pub key modified it in some way (line wrapping it or adding Windows line endings for example)? If you log in to the server using password, does file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys identify it as an OpenSSH RSA public key? Did you create the key pair with the default names (id_rsa, id_rsa.pub)? if not, how are you passing the appropriate key to your ssh command?

@steeldriver They are named the default id_rsa and id_rsa .pub. The command does identify it as an OpenSSH RSA pub key and I don't know how I would pass the appropriate key to the ssh command as every documentation I've seen has shown that you can use just ssh username@hostname and it would automatically find the correct key

@steeldriver I tried using 'ssh -i C:\Users\kingr.ssh\id_rsa user@hostname' however this still resulted in a default to password auth
